# Sort a query by how many post it have in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, categories

I've some question about doing a WP query.

I have a Custom Post Type called "Product" and it has some categories like Electronics > Smartphones.

Also, I've another CPT called "Reviews", so when a user is logged in, he can create a review for a product, so I've in the "Reviews" CPT a Custom Field with the "Product" Post id.

What I need is do a query, to show on the user's profile page, that shows the user interested categories, like how many "Reviews" the user have made about, electronics, how many of smartphones, etc.

Is there any way to do it in one single query? Or should I add to the "Reviews" CPT the same category as well? So there I can list it.

PS: if this is not the correct place to put this question, can anyone help me to put it in the correct place, thanks.

Comment: I doubt the `WP_Query` object can handle a query such as this. I think you'll need to write a custom SQL query and run it through the `WPDB` object instead.

Answer (score 0):

Apply this Argument in Your Post

```
$args= array(
            'numberposts' => 5,
            'category' => 0, 
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC', 
            'meta_value' =>'', 

        );
```